# Error trying to use a prepared statement in mysql.connector to updae a database

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm fairly new to databases/python and i've read that you're supposed to use prepared statements instead of string formatting

I had

```
conn = mysql.connector.connect(user=user, password=pw, host=host, database=db)
cursor = conn.cursor(prepared=True)

cursor.execute(f"DESCRIBE {table_name}")
fetch = cursor.fetchall()
table_columns = [col[0] for col in fetch]
```

where table_name was the name of my sql table. I'm attampting to change it to the code below

```
# Get the names of all the columns in the mySQL table
statement = "DESCRIBE %s"
cursor.execute(statement, (table_name,))
fetch = cursor.fetchall()
table_columns = [col[0] for col in fetch]
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1
```

Comment: First, are you sure this is your real code?  The code has `%s`, but the error message says you have `?`.

Comment: Second, I'm not sure you can use parameters with DESCRIBE.  As far as I'm aware, you can only use parameters as placeholders for _column values_, i.e. for INSERT, DELETE, LIKE, etc.

Comment: yea - i thought that was weird as well. I tried switching the %s to the ? but it gave me the same error and the documentation had the %s. Point taken on the DESCRIBE then. Is it ok to leave it the way I originally had it?

Comment: what about with something like this: check_existence = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM projects WHERE %s". This will run but not returning the right data. Makes me think I have something wrong in the syntax

Comment: I'm surprised that even runs.  It needs to be something like `WHERE column_name = %s`, no?